# Question about a discord bot and channel id

Tags: javascript, bots, discord, discord.js

I'm trying to program a function into my discord bot, to make this function i need to get the channel id where the user is when he write the command(Not the channel id of the text channel where he write the command, but the vocal channel where he is at the moment).
I have been looking for about 8 hours online and among the discord js functions, but I can't find anything, can someone help me?

Answer (score 0):

The command i was looking for is: `Message.member.voice.channelID` if anyone needs.